# MediaStore.Images.Media lowers the quality of the image stored to gallery

Tags: android, jpeg, mediastore

I'm saving the screenshot of the app to Gallery via -

```
//screenshot
private void screenshot()
{
    Uri photo = lomography();
    String photopath = photo.getPath();
    try {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), photopath, "name" , "desc");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The image stored at the photopath is of high quality:

[image]

But when I navigate to Gallery and open the same photo, this is the low JPEG version with several compression artifacts:

[image]

Why does the Gallery image a JPEG version when the original file is a PNG?
How can I save the high res version to the gallery?

I [read here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/aSOOZz86JsQ) that the trick is in 'Register image with ContentResolver::insert'.

But I'm using getContentResolver.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This was the answer.
I mean '**this**' was the missing part in the code.

Instead of 'MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(**getContentResolver**()'.
I should have used MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(**this.getContentResolver**()

Problem solved.

Comment: Both are same, by default, its calling in `this` instance.

Comment: @xmenW.K. The image quality was significantly lower, like a vga camera.

Comment: The marked answer is not the solution though, you are calling same method, no matter use `this` or not.

Comment: @xmenW.K. adding 'this' surprisingly solved the problem. I guess it had something to do with the context. Without this, it created a thumbnail quality screenshot.

Comment: and did you try to remove `this` and test again ?

Comment: @xmenW.K. It was causing problem without this and that is why I wrote the question. I found the solution on Google forums.

Comment: The MediaStore.insertImage source shows that images are indeed compressed drastically: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#L904 -- 50% quality!

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, open the delcaration of the "MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage" method, copy and paste the code you need into your own class, then where its compressing the image at 50% change it to 100%.